# Math calculation in Watson Conversation response

Tags: javascript, calculated-field, watson-conversation

I am pretty starting some flows and testing, maybe this is a fool question, sorry.
I have a flow asking for some inputs (amount, and currency). I want the conversation bot to answer the total (amount * currency). I did several researches, but nothing yet using the "context" section, even storing values in variables, when calling $var1 * $var2, it does not do the math on the response.
Any suggestion? Eg: calling a javascript for that? Or what?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the conversation service you want to evaluate something as an expression by using `<? ?>` - in your case this means writing this `<? $var1 * $var2 ?>` to Watson answer field in the UI.

Comment: Hi, Michal. Thanks for answering so quickly. I tested it, had to do some converts, and it is working just fine. Thanks a lot!